# Strange behaviour with Behat/Mink for form filling

Tags: symfony, bdd, behat, mink

I use Behat and Mink for integration testing in my Symfony2 project and have used the following syntax across the site with success, but in one place I am getting really strange errors that don't seem to make any sense (to me):

The scenario is as follows:

```
Scenario: I can create a new event
    Given I am on "/event/new"
    When I fill in the following:
        | Title             | Test Event        |
        | Event Details     | Description       |
        And I check the "Active" option for "Published"
        And I press "Save"
    Then I should see "New event posted successfully!"
```

and I get the following error:

```
Form submit button for field with xpath 
"(//html/.//*[self::input | self::textarea | self::select][not(./@type = 'submit' 
or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type = 'hidden')][(((./@id = 'Title' or ./@name = 'Title') 
or ./@id = //label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 'Title')]/@for) or 
./@placeholder = 'Title')] | .//label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 
'Title')]//.//*[self::input | self::textarea | self::select][not(./@type = 'submit' or 
./@type = 'image' or ./@type = 'hidden')])[1]"not found
In step `And I fill in the following:'.
```

So I figure it's erroring on the "Title" field, but the error message implies it is looking for a submit button!? If I change the field name in the scenario to one that doesn't exist I get the expected (and more readable) "Field not found" error message.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to a single line within a js script included in the form:

`var errorString = '<div class="help-inline time-error">Please select a valid time for your event</div>';`

if I change "div" to "span", the test passes - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that including the html snippet:

```
var errorString = '<div class="help-inline time-error">Please select a valid time for your event</div>';
```

in the javascript section within the form messed up the DOM parsing - placing the div content in the actual form and hiding it with css, then using jquery selectors to place it where I want it worked a treat!